# Email is not getting from IIS application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have using office 365 smtp for sending email in my application. it is working and getting emails in my local system while debugging in visual studio. But when hosted to iis in server the email is not getting, no erroris showing.

here is my smtp settings in web config

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="myOffice365account">
        <network host="smtp.office365.com" port="587" password="myPassword" userName="myOffice365account" defaultCredentials="false" enableSsl="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

and this is the code for sending email

```
public bool SendMail(string[] to, string subject, string body,Attachment attachement=null)
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.Subject = subject;
    mail.Body = body;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
    mail.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email_FromAddress"]);

    if (attachement !=null)
    {

        mail.Attachments.Add(attachement);
    }

    mail.To.Add(string.Join(",", to));

    SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient();
    mailClient.Send(mail);
    return true;
}
```

after clicking send button in iis hosted application the success message is coming no error, but the mail not getting. The port 587 is already opened.

Is there anyother settings in server or code for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No errors at all? Nothing in the server logs? Are you logging a and throwing exceptions in your app, and not suppressing them in some higher try/catch block? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc(v=vs.110).aspx shows all the possible exceptions the send operation could throw. If I had to guess I'd say maybe your IIS server (or possibly the specific account under which the web app runs) doesn't have permission to access the SMTP server. Unless for some reason this code isn't even being called within your app, then there should be _some_ kind of error.

Comment: Then again, of course, even if an email can be _sent_, that provides no guarantee that it will be _received_. All sorts of other factors can come into play. I don't know if office365 provides a way for you to look at its logs for your account so you can guarantee that it at least received the message from your app and tried to pass it on.

Comment: Why does `SendMail` return a boolean? Is there a try/catch above this code in the callstack?

Answer (score -1):

I hard the same issue that my solution works locally but on the production server all the email sent were not delivery. I have to Event Viewer on the server ---> Windows Logs ---> Application, Then I send and email the log drop and I was able to see the error